# Allow only a certain user type to see a field in an edit view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My system lets users place orders and I'd like for them to be able to edit these orders however I am planning on adding a order status variable to this edit form how can i make it so that ONLY staff members can see this. I have tried using @if (ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole but this did not seem to work.

edit methods

```
// GET: Orders/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            CustomerOrder order = db.CustomerOrders.Find(id);
            if (order == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(order);
        }

            // POST: Orders/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(CustomerOrder order)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(order);
        }
```

edit view

```
@model bob.Models.CustomerOrder
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <h4>Order</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostalCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostalCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostalCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @if (ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Stores Manager"))
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

please note the order status variable I would like to do this with is not yet a thing. But if you could show me how to do it with one of the other variables I would be greatful.

Comment: When you say "variable", you mean "property" of your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys got it to work by doing this have not extensively tested it so any problems that could arise feel free to tell me however this seems to work

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @if (User.IsInRole("Stores Manager"))
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Email)
            }
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Views have an `IPrincipal` property called `User`:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Stores Manager"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
}
```

If you want to submit the form when user is not in Store Manager role, then these properties have to be not required in your model.

Comment: By doing this though when a user edits their order. Will the email stay as it was before

Comment: Let me give you a little context. I dont actually want to do it with email the property i want to do it with OrderStatus which I have not added will be given the value 1 at checkout, 1 corrasponding to the OrderStatus "Ordered" And  I would like it to stay this way unless a staff member edits it#

Comment: That depends on the way you save your model. When a NOT "Store Manager" user submits the form, `Email` will be null on parameter that holds the model in your action of your controller. Then, if you save directly the `CustomerOrder` entity that comes on the parameter then  `Email` will be updated to null. The same applies for `OrderStatus`.

Comment: Got any suggestions of how I could do this another way